# 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '<<error type>>'

Tags: swift

I keep getting these error messages and I don't know how to fix it:

> 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '<>'
>
> Use of undeclared type 'M13Checkbox'

```
import UIKit
import M13Checkbox
class GroupMemberTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var MemberStateCheckBox: M13Checkbox!
@IBOutlet weak var memberName: UILabel!

var user: User!
}
```

Comment: Show us the declaration of `M13Checkbox` type. Is it a `class` or `struct`? Also, the variable name `MemberStateCheckBox` looks suspiciously like the name of some type, itself (e.g. starting with uppercase letter, etc.). Do you have your variable name and type definition backwards, by some chance?

Comment: M13Checkbox might be from this framework https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox, then you probably forgot to `import M13Checkbox`